# Cannot find libfftw_mpi.so

Tags: shared-libraries, mpi, fftw

I am trying to compile the GADGET2 hydrodynamic code. I have installed the FFTW2 library as required (once manually and once with sudo apt-get install fftw2). When I type 'make' I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrfftw_mpi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw_mpi
```

After some research I found that what this means is that it cannot find the librfftw_mpi.so and the libfftw_mpi.so library. There are no such libraries in my installation or anywhere in the computer. The only thing that exists is librfftw_mpi.so.2 and libfftw_mpi.so.2. Apparently, sudo-renaming the extensions leads to broken links between files, so I ran out of ideas on how to proceed from this point on.

The only place where these are mentioned inside the code, are in my Makefile:

```
ifeq (NOTYPEPREFIX_FFTW,$(findstring NOTYPEPREFIX_FFTW,$(OPT)))   
 FFTW_LIB = $(FFTW_LIBS) -lrfftw_mpi -lfftw_mpi -lrfftw -lfftw
else
 ifeq (DOUBLEPRECISION_FFTW,$(findstring DOUBLEPRECISION_FFTW,$(OPT)))
  FFTW_LIB = $(FFTW_LIBS) -ldrfftw_mpi -ldfftw_mpi -ldrfftw -ldfftw
 else
  FFTW_LIB = $(FFTW_LIBS) -lsrfftw_mpi -lsfftw_mpi -lsrfftw -lsfftw
 endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the libfftw_mpi.so and librfftw_mpi.so libraries by typing:
    sudo apt-get install **fftw-dev**
and by relocating them to the appropriate path. However, a new problem arose, namely:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libfftw_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_request_null'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/librfftw_mpi.so: undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_f2c'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libfftw_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_double'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libfftw_mpi.so: undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_comm_world'
```

Comment: It looks like FFTW was built with Open MPI but you are now trying to build your app with MPICH.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to sort this out. I got rid of the aforementioned problem by changing the paths of the libraries, but now it has become more complicated, as it seems I have ended up with sth that goes by the name 'cross-compiler build', which is not (?) suggested.